# MySQL isn't starting anymore

Tags: mysql

I have a Problem with my MySQL-Server and apt-get install on Debian 8.

Here is the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.59-0+deb8u1) ...
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I that my MySQL-Server startup again?

Regards,

Comment: if you post this question to other network (dba), you might get better response

Comment: What is dba????

Comment: This question is best directed toward a DBA or Unix-focused Stack Exchange site such as [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). However, you might find the following Q&A helpful: [_Mysql-server-5.5 Installation Error_, AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384234/e-mysql-server-5-5-installation-error).

Comment: When you do post this elsewhere please include the mysql logs detailing the failed startup